# Switch back to http from https in SharePoint (MOSS 2007)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, http, https

I have a MOSS 2007 instance and a web app (Site Collection) in port 80 that has an extension through port 443 to enable https.

This instance has an asp.net web app that is inside the Site Collection. This asp.net web app enters https protocol when one of its qualifying aspx webforms is called, but when the user leaves the form the https protocol is still active for the rest of the navigation.

You must know this:

1. All site content pages must be and are sharepoint pages (site content).
2. All URLs are and must be relative.
3. The asp.net web app is using an http module that can handle http-->https and viceversa (it works by overriding the page_load event).

I'm looking for a native way to do this in SharePoint (MOSS 2007) or using IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to link the user to `http://./server-relative-url` at the end of your custom form? I don't know if this will work but its the best I can think of if you must use relative URLs.

**Edit:**

I don't like the 'feel' of it, but the only thing I can think of right now is to use an HTTP module to update the https links in the page. If it's SharePoint-generated content that you need to update en masse then this is practical and efficient, and perhaps the only option?

You would need to work out some logic (maybe add something to the page) so the HTTP module knows when to activate.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, I think I can do that only in an asp.net button or link, but what I'm trying to do is that when the user clicks any SharePoint-Content-Generated link it drops the https also. Remember that in SharePoint you have controls like the top-nav-bar and many others that provide the user with an un-controlled exit from the webform. I want that unprotected content switches by itself to http protocol.